# Qlik sense - Customize label on drill-down dimension

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to customize labels on drill-down dimensions and after doing some research this is apparently not possible in frontend? It's a problem when you use hierarchy dimension in drilldown and the field names don't have appropriate labels for the visual object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you cannot use expressions to dynamically modify Master Dimension labels. If you're willing to go outside the box, though, you can get clever with `If()` statements to simulate a drilldown dimension.

Say you had a drilldown dimension that was set up with 3 dimensions in the hierarchy:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense master dimension properties]

What you could do is create a new variable called **vDrilldownDim** or something like that and use this expression as the definition:

```
=If( GetPossibleCount(TransLineID) = 1
   , If( GetPossibleCount(TransID) = 1
       , 'Dim1'
       , 'TransID'
      )
    , 'TransLineID'
)
```

This expression utilizes the `GetPossibleCount()` function to check whether just 1 value in a given field is `Possible` to select, at which point it would dynamically "drilldown" to the next field in the expression that has more than 1 value possible to select, which is essentially how a drilldown Master Dimension works, too.

In your chart objects, you can reference the variable in your field like this:

```
=[$(vDrilldownDim)]
```

...and in your field label like this:

```
='$(vDrilldownDim)'
```

Then the behavior is basically the same as a drilldown Master Dimension but you can modify that field label expression above to be whatever you need it to be, or even create a second variable to handle it.

[image: Screen recording of Qlik Sense drilldown dimension comparison]

Comment: I created a variable as per description - created a single master dimension and reffered to the variable in the Field - used the same syntax in Label expression and replaced field with desired label names. And voila, it worked! Thank you!